# Admob shows Test ads but my ads not appear

Tags: admob

I'm worked on source code app , the apps shows Test ads only , so I want to add my admob units in app , but the code not showing my ads in app  .
what can I change in this codes please .
thanks for all .

this is the mean ads class .

PTAdAdMobBridge.java

```js
package com.secrethq.ads;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.android.MemoryManager;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

public class PTAdAdMobBridge {
 private static final String TAG = "PTAdAdMobBridge";
 private static Cocos2dxActivity activity;
 private static WeakReference<Cocos2dxActivity> s_activity;
 private static AdView adView;
 private static InterstitialAd interstitial;
 private static LinearLayout layout;

 private static native String bannerId();
 private static native String interstitialId();
 private static native void interstitialDidFail();
 private static native void bannerDidFail();

 private static boolean isBannerScheduledForShow = false;
 private static boolean isInterstitialScheduledForShow = false;

 public static void initBridge(Cocos2dxActivity activity){
  Log.v(TAG, "PTAdAdMobBridge  -- INIT");


  PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity = new WeakReference<Cocos2dxActivity>(activity);
  PTAdAdMobBridge.activity = activity;
  MobileAds.initialize(PTAdAdMobBridge.activity, PTAdAdMobBridge.bannerId());

  PTAdAdMobBridge.initBanner();
  PTAdAdMobBridge.initInterstitial();

 }

 public static void initBanner(){
  Log.v(TAG, "PTAdAdMobBridge  -- initBanner");
  PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
   public void run() {

    if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView != null){
     return;
    }
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)PTAdAdMobBridge.activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout( PTAdAdMobBridge.activity );
    frameLayout.addView( layout );

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
      AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView = new AdView( PTAdAdMobBridge.activity );
    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setAdUnitId( PTAdAdMobBridge.bannerId() );

    layout.addView(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView, adViewParams);
    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );

    AdRequest adRequest = getAdRequest();
    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.loadAd( adRequest );
   }
  });

 }

 public static boolean isBannerVisible(){
  if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView == null){
   return false;
  }
  else{
   if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
    return true;
   }
   else{
    return false;
   }
  }
 }

 public static void initInterstitial(){
  Log.v(TAG, "PTAdAdMobBridge  -- initInterstitial");
  PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
   public void run() {

    if(PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial != null){
     return;
    }

    AdRequest adRequest = getAdRequest();
    MemoryManager.manage(PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitialId());
    MemoryManager.pause(PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitialId());
    PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial = new InterstitialAd( PTAdAdMobBridge.activity );
    PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.setAdUnitId( PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitialId() );
    PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAdLoaded() {
      if(PTAdAdMobBridge.isInterstitialScheduledForShow){
       PTAdAdMobBridge.showFullScreen();
      }
     }

     @Override
     public void onAdClosed() {
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
     }

     @Override
     public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
      if ( !isInterstitialScheduledForShow )
       return;

      PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitialDidFail();
     }
    });

    PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
   }
  });
 }



 public static void showFullScreen(){
  Log.v(TAG, "showFullScreen");

  isInterstitialScheduledForShow = true;

  if(PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial != null){
   PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     if(MemoryManager.on() && PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.isLoaded()){
      PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.show();
      PTAdAdMobBridge.isInterstitialScheduledForShow = false;
      PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.loadAd(getAdRequest());
     }
     else{
      PTAdAdMobBridge.isInterstitialScheduledForShow = true;
     }
     MemoryManager.manageMemory();
    }
   });
  }
 }

 public static void showBannerAd(){
  Log.v(TAG, "showBannerAd");

  isBannerScheduledForShow = true;

  if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView != null){

   PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     AdRequest adRequest = getAdRequest();

     PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.loadAd(adRequest);
     PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
       if ( !isBannerScheduledForShow )
        return;

       Log.v(TAG, "Banner Ad Failed To Load");
       PTAdAdMobBridge.bannerDidFail();
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded() {
       Log.v(TAG, "Banner Ad Loaded");
       PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( isBannerScheduledForShow ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE );
      }
     });
     PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
    }
   });
  }



 }

 public static void hideBannerAd(){
  Log.v(TAG, "hideBannerAd");

  isBannerScheduledForShow = false;

  if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView != null){
   PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    }
   });
  }
 }

 private static AdRequest getAdRequest(){
  // Create an ad request. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
  // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
  // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    // uncomment to get test ads
    //.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
    .build();
  return adRequest;
 }

}
```

the main class PTPlayer.java

```js
package com.buildbox.game;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.MemoryManager;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesActivityResultCodes;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdAdMobBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdAppLovinBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdChartboostBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdFacebookBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdHeyzapBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdInMobiBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdLeadBoltBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdRevMobBridge;
import com.secrethq.store.PTStoreBridge;
import com.secrethq.utils.PTJniHelper;
import com.secrethq.utils.PTServicesBridge;

import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;
import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView;

import croco.fruirt.ninja.run.R;

public class PTPlayer extends Cocos2dxActivity {

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  try {
   Log.v("----------","onActivityResult: request: " + requestCode + " result: "+ resultCode);
   if(PTStoreBridge.iabHelper().handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)){
    Log.v("-----------", "handled by IABHelper");
   }
   else if(requestCode == PTServicesBridge.RC_SIGN_IN){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
     PTServicesBridge.instance().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    else if(resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_SIGN_IN_FAILED){
     int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services: Sign in error", duration);
     toast.show();
    }
    else if(resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_APP_MISCONFIGURED){
     int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services: App misconfigured", duration);
     toast.show();
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.v("-----------", "onActivityResult FAIL on iabHelper : " + e.toString());
  }
 }

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  PTServicesBridge.initBridge(this, getString( R.string.app_id ));
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
 }

 @Override
 public void onNativeInit(){
  initBridges();
 }

 private void initBridges(){
  PTStoreBridge.initBridge( this );


  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
   PTAdChartboostBridge.initBridge(this);
  }

  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kRevMob")) {
   PTAdRevMobBridge.initBridge(this);
  }

  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kInMobi")) {
   PTAdInMobiBridge.initBridge(this);
  }

  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kAdMob") || PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kFacebook")) {
   PTAdAdMobBridge.initBridge(this);
  }

  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kAppLovin")) {
   PTAdAppLovinBridge.initBridge(this);
  }

  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kLeadBolt")) {
   PTAdLeadBoltBridge.initBridge(this);
  }

  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kFacebook")) {
   PTAdFacebookBridge.initBridge(this);
  }

  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kHeyzap")) {
   PTAdHeyzapBridge.initBridge(this);
  }
 }

 @Override
 public Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView onCreateView() {
  Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = new Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView(this);
  glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0);

  return glSurfaceView;
 }

 static {
  System.loadLibrary("player");
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  MemoryManager.onResume();
  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
   PTAdChartboostBridge.onResume( this );
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  MemoryManager.onStart();
  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
   PTAdChartboostBridge.onStart( this );
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  MemoryManager.onStop();
  if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
   PTAdChartboostBridge.onStop( this );
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  MemoryManager.onDestroy();
  super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  MemoryManager.onBackPressed();
  exitConfirmation(this);
 }

 private void exitConfirmation(final Activity activity) {

  AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
  alertDlg.setMessage("Do you Want Exit ?");
  alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

  alertDlg.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    activity.finish();
   }
  });

  alertDlg.setNeutralButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
   }
  });

  alertDlg.create().show();
 }
}
```

the AndroidManifest.xml :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="croco.fruirt.ninja.run">

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="com.android.MemoryManager">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.buildbox.game.PTPlayer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- FACEBOOK SDK --><!--
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
--><!-- FACEBOOK SDK -->

        <!-- ADMOB -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            />

        <!-- ADMOB -->

        <!--
        <activity
            android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

            -->


        <!-- HEYZAP --><!--
  <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapIncentivizedActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
  <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapInterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
  <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.MediationTestActivity" />
  <activity android:name="com.fyber.ads.ofw.OfferWallUnityActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
  <service android:name="com.fyber.cache.CacheVideoDownloadService"
           android:exported="false" />
--><!-- HEYZAP -->

        <!-- APPLOVIN SDK --><!--
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity" />
  <meta-data
            android:name="applovin.sdk.key"
            android:value="{{AppLovin_SDK_key}}" />
--><!-- APPLOVIN SDK -->

        <!-- REVMOB --><!--
        <activity android:name="com.revmob.FullscreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.revmob.app.id" android:value="{{RevMobMediaID}}"/>
--><!-- REVMOB -->

    </application>

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

the main layout main.xml :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxEditText 
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"/>

    <org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/game_gl_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/revMobBanner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
              
       <com.google.android.gms.ads.adMobView 
          android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    
               />
  
 </LinearLayout>
 
<!-- <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >
</com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView>

<com.applovin.adview.AppLovinAdView
    xmlns:applovin="http://schemas.applovin.com/android/1.0"
    android:id="@+id/ALadview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="visible"
    applovin:loadAdOnCreate="true" /> -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52378933/6096821

Comment: sorry this is not help me

Answer (score 0):

as you see here

```
private static AdRequest getAdRequest(){
    // Create an ad request. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
    // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            // uncomment to get test ads
            //.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
            .build();
    return adRequest;
}
```

at this line `AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                // uncomment to get test ads
                //.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                .build();`

you should add your device id between the brackets ,you get the id from Logcat after running the game or the app on real device using AndroidStudio it will show in logcat like this Device 04f32c5b5015b7b5.

first Uncomment this 
`//.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")`