# How to solve Admob ExecutionExceptions?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I've been trying to implement Google Admob ads to my brand new app.

I've been handling an error code of 0 (internal error), and "Ads: Error waiting for future" exceptions for hours.

I have an Admob account with payments methods since this morning. I have been following the Google Admob tutorial for Interstitial Ads with my credentials **and** the test credentials. I have updated the Google Play Services. Anything worked.

Now I've downloaded the Admob Sample App in order to test the interstitials in another app... and it didn't work too!

I don't even know if my phone is the problem (Samsung Galaxy S8 Exynos) or it's Google!

I've been looking on the internet for hours and nothing worked. Please Help. Ask me anything you need to help me, I don't even know which files do you need.

Comment: The issue seems to be known and specific to the emulator. Try to use an actual device or a different emulator. See [groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/google-admob-ads-sdk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/google-admob-ads-sdk/android)

Comment: I'm using a device

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: We noticed that our Samsung Galaxy S8 test devices are not showing admob ads but all our other ones are, so I'm suspecting some issue either related to screen size (with the atypical screen configuration on the S8) or a Samsung implementation problem specific to that phone.

Comment: OK... so we just restarted those devices and all of a sudden they are now showing ads.  Very weird.

Comment: Any conclusion? My problem still there

Comment: @user1608385 are your Samsung S8 test devices rooted?

Answer (score 0):

This is what google says

> "It could be that you have only recently created a new Ad Unit ID and requesting for live ads. It could take a couple of hours
>   for promotions to begin getting served if that will be that case. In
>   the event that you are getting test advertisements then your execution
>   is fine. Simply hold up a couple of hours and check whether you can
>   get live advertisements at that point. If not, can send us your Ad
>   Unit ID for us to investigate."

so you have need to wait for the few hours :)

Comment: I waited one day, nothing happens, and I said that the sample app is not working too...